# PHP, escape any characters

Tags: php

Can I escape any character in string without using symbol "\"?
For example, programming language C# allows specify string, which does not have special characters:

```
@"c:\webserver\".Equals("c:\\webserver\\") // <== return true
```

Thanks for answers and sorry for my poor English!

Comment: I am not able to understand exactly what you want to do. Why don't you show some post, or stubs: input and expect output etfc.

Comment: The example you provided has double quote and backslash escaped using "\"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you want to automatically add slashes?

Then you can use built in php function:

> addslashes();

http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Comment: Yes, it's. Thanks, man. At this moment I can't vote up your answer, but I promise make it in future.

Comment: Then make +1 not -1 :) Or just accept the answer

Comment: So all you wanted to share with your question was that you absolutely had no clue about PHP strings and weren't even able to look on the strings PHP manual page? Just in case you find it here: http://php.net/string

Comment: @Andrew: Better keep asking questions back to comments, not answers, if you need clarification with a question. You might be lucky to hit the right answer, however the ambiguous question will rot on the website afterwards.

Comment: Why you is so angry, hakre?

Comment: @hakre: I suggest you to find out how much reputation one needs to add comment right after original question

Comment: @Andrew: I know that you need a hundred and you don't have it. But that doesn't make my comment wrong.

Answer (score 1):

to escape use addslashes(); and stripslashes() to remove added slashes

Comment: escape what? I don't understand.

Comment: hakre, these characters: single quote ('), double quote ("), backslash (\\) and NUL (the NULL byte).